# Finotes not reporting issues

Tags: android, issue-tracking, bug-reporting

I am using Automated bug reporting SDK finotes in android.
I had integrated the sdk and it was reporting issues during development
but I created a release build for testing. Looks like it is not reporting issues anymore.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As per their documentation make sure that you add the following  in your pro-guard configuration

`-keep class com.finotes.android.finotescore.* { *; }`

`-keepclassmembers class * {
   @com.finotes.android.finotescore.annotation.Observe *;
}`

Also make sure that, in init() function doesn’t have their dry run turned ON

dryRun flag will prevent the issues from syncing to their dashboard.

For release build, change init() in Application class to,
`Fn.init(this);`